# Import data into SEOmatic

Tags: plugin-import, plugin-seomatic

I'm trying to import data with the [import](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/import) plugin into entries with a [SEOmatic](https://github.com/nystudio107/seomatic) field. How is structured this field and how can I insert the data?